# Struct Codable. Unable to Encode nested json

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have checked severa other questions asked on SO, even though they look similar they did not address my needs and challenges I currently have in an implementation. The questions and answer I have seen so far addresses more of Decodable. However I am currently having issue wit Encodable

I have nested JSON structure Like the below.  I am able to successfully  decoable and pass the json

```
"data": {
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "tKey": "XXXXXXXX",
    "tID": "XXXXX",
    "type": "XXXXX",
    "hasEvent": true,
    "location": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "cover": {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "parentId": "XXXXXXX",
        "parentName": "XXXXXX",
        "pop": {
            "logo": "*********",
        }
},
"men": [
  {
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "title": "XXXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "title": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "title": "XXXXXX"
  }
],
"homes": [],
"homeTypes": [{
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "subMenuId": "XXXXXXXX",
    "type": "Flat",
    "data": {
      "latitude": 29.767,
      "longitude": 0,0000,
    },
    "datas": null,
    "component": null
  },
  {
    "id": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "subMenuId": "XXXXX",
    "type": "Bubgalow",
    "data": {
      "id": "XXXXXXXXX,
      "title": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "summary": "Hello;",
  }
 }
]
}
```

The decodable works fine as I am able to pass in response from the server and populate tableview. However on trying to encode using encodable protocol it does not seem to work. Please find the code snippet below that I have tried:

```
Struct DataObject: Codable {
var id: String = ""
var location: String = ""
var tKey: String = ""
var tId: String = ""
var cover: cover!
var homeTypes: [Type] = [TYpe]()

var flat = Flat()
var bungalow = Bungalow()

var flat = Flat()
var bungalow = Bungalow()

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case type = "type"
    case location = "location"
    case tKey = "tKey"
    case tId = "tId"
    case cover = "cover"
    case homeTypes = "homeTypes"
}

enum ComponentCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case type = "type"
    case component = "component"
}


required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    if container.contains(.tKey) {
        tKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tKey) ?? ""
    }
    if container.contains(.tId) {
        tId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tId) ?? ""
    }
    let typeRawValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    if let tempType = SomeType(rawValue: typeRawValue) {
        type = tempType
    }
    if container.contains(.location) {
        location = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .location) ?? ""
    }
    cover = try container.decode(Cover.self, forKey: .cover)
    homeTypes = try container.decode([HomeTypes].self, forKey: .component)
     for homeType in homeTypes {

          switch homeType.type {
           case .flat:
                flat = homeType.flat
          }
          case .bungalow:
                bungalow = homeType.bungalow
     }

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(location, forKey: .location)
    try container.encode(tKey, forKey: .tKey)
    try container.encode(tId, forKey: .tId)
    try container.encode(cover, forKey: .cover)
    //let rawValueType = try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)

    var homes = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .component)
    try homeTypes.forEach {
        try homes.encode($0)
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? have you wrapped the encode call in a do/catch and caught the output error from the console?

Comment: @Scriptable yes I have done that, when I print after encoding it I can see that it actually encoded, however when I attempt to decode it kept on giving me nil

Comment: When using `Codable` you are discouraged from assigning default values to the struct members, just declare the type. And you can omit the explicit `CodingKeys` if all keys match the struct member names. And the code doesn't compile anyway.

Comment: @vadian , that is noted, but will not fix the issue I currently have. Can you help to fix the issue

Comment: I'd recommend to use multiple structs rather than decoding the JSON into a single level struct.

Comment: @vadian Can you advise how to loop through an array in when encoding usuing an enum raw type. I think thats where I may have the issue

Comment: This code isn't  even close to compiling. You've got `Type`, `TYpe`  and `HomeTypes` that all seem to be the same thing. Please add the real code that you're using - preferably updated taking into account the comments above and my answer.

Comment: No I can't because the JSON is not valid and the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Tidy these up first and then you might have a clearer idea what's going on

- Use `let` rather than `var`. If a value doesn't exist, use `nil` rather than an empty string.

  ```
  struct DataObject: Codable {

      let id: String
      let location: String?
      let tKey: String?
      let tId: String?
      let cover: Cover
      let homeTypes: [Type]
  }
  ```
- You don't need to give your `CodingKeys` a string value if they match the json keys. So just…

  ```
  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case id, type, location, tKey, tId, cover, homeTypes
  }
  ```
- No need to test if a key exists if you're using `decodeIfPresent`

  ```
  tKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tKey)
  ```
- Make `Type: Codable`, then

  ```
  try container.encode(homeTypes, forKey: .homeTypes)
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Can you advise how to loop through an array in when encoding. I think whats where I may have the issue

Comment: FYI, you don't need `CodingKeys` *at all* if the keys are the same as the strings.

Comment: I already made Type conform to codable and yet I am not able to loop through it like i did when decoding